# java send json to php and insert into mysql, but return null

Tags: java, php, mysql, json, post

I am going to send a php via java program and insert it into MYSQL

I can successfully insert by browser (not return null in MYSQL column)
But return null column from java

```
URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    DataOutputStream os;
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                    conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
                    // add header
                    conn.setDoInput(true); 
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); 
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); 
                    JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
                    jsonParam.put("type", type);
                    jsonParam.put("question", question);
                    jsonParam.put("answerA", answerA);
                    jsonParam.put("answerB", answerB);
                    jsonParam.put("answerC", answerC);
                    jsonParam.put("answerD", answerD);
                    jsonParam.put("creator", corrctAnswer);

                    //Log.i("JSON", jsonParam.toString());
                    os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                    os.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));
                    //os.writeUTF(jsonParam.toString());
                    os.flush();
                    os.close();
```

[image]

How can I fix the "null" issue

And here is my PHP code

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
$json = $_GET["json"];
$obj = json_decode($json);

$type = $obj -> {"type"};
$question = $obj -> {"question"};
$answerA = $obj -> {"answerA"};
$answerB = $obj -> {"answerB"};
$answerC = $obj -> {"answerC"};
$answerD = $obj -> {"answerD"};
$creator = $obj -> {"creator"};


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "DB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO stjohn (type, question, answerA, answerB, answerC, answerD, creator) VALUES
 (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $type, $question, $answerA, $answerB, $answerC, $answerD, $creator);
$stmt->execute();
echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>
```

Hope someone can help 
I am not good at json and php

Comment: can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: All I see in your question is java code for POSTing a JSON string to some URL. I don't understand what you mean by _return null column from java_. I guess POSTing to this URL runs a PHP script that performs a [SQL] INSERT into a _MySQL_ database, correct?

Comment: the program "jsonParam.put" is not null
But databases occur null after json sent

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things I am not so sure about in your code. One of them is setting multiple request properties in more than one lines.

```
URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");

JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject();
jsonParam.put("type", type);
jsonParam.put("question", question);
jsonParam.put("answerA", answerA);
jsonParam.put("answerB", answerB);
jsonParam.put("answerC", answerC);
jsonParam.put("answerD", answerD);
jsonParam.put("creator", corrctAnswer);

OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(jsonParam.toString().getBytes());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

And putting string in `os.write` while the document explicitly mentions byte input. I am pretty sure this snippet will do the job for you.

Comment: My code is doing with Android TextView and I am sure that the  TextView  return is not null

Comment: put and `int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();` and tell me what do you get if you print this variable

Comment: Also try to print all the variables you are creating the json object just to be sure

Comment: int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode(); 
printout : 200

Comment: and what do you receive in your webservice?

Comment: This is the json print out buy the raw code with 
System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url + URLEncoder.encode(jsonParam.toString(),"UTF-8"));



 http://IP/insert.php?json=%7B%22type%22%3A%22stjohn%22%2C%22question%22%3A%22Q%22%2C%22answerA%22%3A%22A%22%2C%22answerB%22%3A%22B%22%2C%22answerC%22%3A%22C%22%2C%22answerD%22%3A%22D%22%2C%22creator%22%3A%22E%22%7D

Comment: The mysql column still return null when the program return 200

Comment: dont rally understand 
can you please explain ?

Comment: Since I have tried the above code with using
os.write(jsonParam.toString().getBytes());

but still return null

Comment: Sorry I made a bummer, I got confused with application/json and application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: so are there more suggestion? please